# MySQL select help needed

Tags: mysql

```
+---+---+
| A | B |
+---+---+
| 1 | 1 |
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
+---+---+
| 1 | 3 |
+---+---+
| 1 | 4 |
+---+---+
| 2 | 2 |
+---+---+
| 2 | 4 |
+---+---+
| 3 | 2 |
+---+---+
| 4 | 3 |
+---+---+
```

Given a set of values from B, how can I select the value from A that all B values share?  For example:

- The values 1, 2, 3, 4 should return 1
- The values 2, 4 should return 1, 2
- The values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 should return an empty set

So far I have:

```
SELECT A 
FROM (table_A) 
JOIN table_B ON A = A 
WHERE B = '1' OR B = '2' OR B = '3' OR B = '4'
```

That's obviously way off from what I need. I'm really over my head here and have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Are `A` and `B` columns from the same table or 2 different tables?

Comment: `A` and `B` are from two different tables brought together through a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select A 
from tableA
JOIN tableB ON tableA.A = tableB.A
where B in (1,2,3,4)
group by A
having count(distinct B) = 4
```

The number in the `having` clause needs to be the number of elements in the `in` clause.

Comment: Brilliant. `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` count worked perfectly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that `A, B` are unique a group by and having work fine for this.

```
SELECT A 
FROM mytable
WHERE B in (1,2,3,4,5)
GROUP BY A
having count(*)=5;
```